# Laravel Spark doesn't pull in css correctly

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-spark

I am playing around with Spark in order to learn how to use it. I did a new install under Homestead following the install instructions. The css link generated from the page at the route is

```
 <link href="http://spark-test.local:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

No css was generated. So, the home page is jacked. Can anyone help me track down the problem?

**Update**
Here are the warnings I get when I run `npm install`:

```
npm WARN package.json laravel-spark@1.0.12 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/vagrant/projects/spark-test/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/browserify requires   glob@'^4.0.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/vagrant/projects/spark-test/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.14
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/vagrant/projects/spark-test/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-phpspec requires gulp-util@'~2.2.14' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/vagrant/projects/spark-test/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-util,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.6
```

And the gulp errors:

```
 module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'module-deps'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/projects/spark-test/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/browserify/index.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

**Update 2**
After following what Aditya posted in the answer below, everything worked.
I am posting here so others can see the resolution to my NPM dependency errors with gulp.
I finally got past the dependency errors by running

```
 npm update
```

Which broke SASS in my project. I fixed that problem by running

```
 npm rebuild node-sass
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yes this is your problem. Before you run your application do the following steps:

1. Run `php artisan migrate`. This creates user and team tables.
2. Run `npm install` or `sudo npm install` so that it install all the dependencies like Bootstrap and vue.js
3. **Your problem may be here**: Run `gulp`. If you do not have one installed, run `sudo npm install -g gulp`

Comment: When I run npm install I get several NPM WARN responses. Since they are only warnings, and not errors, I tried running GULP - but I get errors.

Comment: I added the npm warns under "Update" in my original question. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Well these are just warnings. Please add gulp errors that you are getting.

Comment: Sorry. I got interrupted. The gulp errors are there now.

Comment: Well, heres a quick fix. Just do `npm install module-name` until the error is not removed. Here, in thus case, the module-name will be replaced by `module-deps`. This is a common error in gulp. If it gives errors, just do the same with `sudo` prefixed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have been installing dependencies for an hour. It seems unending :-) Could something be wrong with my base npm install?

Comment: No. It is common error that even I faced. After just 2hours, even when my internet speed was very less, I completed installation. Just go on. It is endable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90679/discussion-between-roger-creasy-and-aditya-giri).